# Importing a large number of 2d DICOM images and generating a 3D image from them

Tags: performance-tuning, image, conversion, image3d

I would like to construct a 3D image from 900 2D images in DICOM format in a folder. I am fairly new to mathematica and would greatly appreciate your help. I am currently using Mathematica 11. 
I used the following loop code to import all the images. Now the images are stored under the variable names imagevar[1], imagevar[2], imagevar[3] so on till imagevar[968]. Now I am trying to use Image3D to generate the 3d image from these variables and it is working when I incorporate the variables into into Image3D function individually 
(This is the code: Image3D[{imagevar[1],imagevar[2],....,imagevar[968]}]  ) but this would take ridiculously long. 
. I tried using various loop methods to do it faster but it does not seem to work. 
Please explain how to generate the 3d image in a quick way. Thank you.

Comment: What `FileNames["somePath/*.dcm"]` returns for you? Is it a list of filenames? Also please upload somewhere a subset of your images in order to allow us to experiment with them. You can upload for example to https://www.sendspace.com/ or to http://www.filefactory.com/.

Comment: Hello, I have edited the question and have figured out how to import these files. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Without you supplying (a subset of) the images, it'd be hard to help you.

Comment: It looks like you want `Image3D[Array[imagevar, 968]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simon Woods has provided an answer that is correct as far as I can tell from the question:

```
Image3D@Array[imagevar, 968] (* or Image3D@Table[imagevar[k], {k,968}] etc.*)
```

This answer can't improve on that per se, but I wanted to point out a few things about using DICOM files in Mathematica:

1. Mathematica's `Image3D` is made for images and not for MRImages; when you load your data into an `Image3D`, it will normalize all of the values to be in the range of 0-1. For most MRI this doesn't matter, but if you are hoping to be rely on the voxel contrast to be a particular value (e.g., some programs rely on white matter voxels to be approximately a certain value), you'll lose that ability.
2. If you are dealing with brain data, then one way around this problem is to convert the file to a Nifti file (e.g., using [FreeSurfer](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/) or some other free sofrware) then load it using the [Neurotica](https://github.com/noahbenson/Neurotica) package, which is freely available on github. If you've imported Neurotica, `Import["someFile.nii", "NifTI"]` will return an `MRImage3D` object (which is defined by the library); these objects imitate `Image3D` objects but store the original values instead of rescaled values. (They also have some reorientation functions defined on them if you are dealing with oriented brain data.) Note: Neurotica is a research toolkit I maintain; it's mostly for cortical surface analysis so the volumetric routines aren't well tested. I would only recommend this if you are dealing with brain data and want the original values preserved.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it seems to be working. Also if I wanted to make the 3d image using only a section of the Images (say images 200 to 300), will Image3D[Array[imagevar, 200,300]] work?

Comment: You'll need to do something like `Image3D[Array[imagevar, 100, {200,300}]]` or `Image3D@Table[imagevar[k], {k, 200, 300}]; you can refer to this help page: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html